# How can I get the end result of my code to be an encrypted text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, translate

I am trying to take an input from the user and using the methods of the string module, I want to translate the input to the encrypted text as per the code.

I have tried the same thing three times and still I am getting the error that says:
"ValueError: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length"

Although, in my code I have already checked for the length and both come out to be same.

I am using Python 3.x

```
# Trial 3

import string

in_text = string.ascii_lowercase
out_text = (string.digits * 2) + string.digits[0:6]

print(len(in_text))
print(len(out_text))

translated_text = str.maketrans(usr_in, usr_out)

my_str = input().lower()
print(my_str.translate(translated_text))
```

I expect to receive the result to be a text that maps the ascii to the numbers and whenever I input a string, I get an encrypted output.

Comment: where did you define usr_in, usr_out?

Comment: You're using the wrong variables in your `str.maketrans` call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to map lower ascii to digits

you should do it like this

```py
import string

in_text = string.ascii_lowercase
out_text = string.digits * 2 + string.digits[0: 6]

translated_text = str.maketrans(in_text, out_text)
my_str = input().lower()

print(my_str.translate(translated_text))
```

OUTPUT:

```
λ python3 s.py
hello, world
74114, 24713
```

Comment: But, once the code gets encrypted into numbers, if I try to make up the same sentence I entered again from the numbers generated, I am unable to do it.

Comment: @AbhinandanSharma Of course you are unable to do that, because you map different characters to the same digits... this "encryption" of yours is not reversible.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thank you for commenting and letting me know the answer. Your response is highly appreciated.